# How to update from libogg 1.2.2 to libogg 1.3.0 in Ubuntu 12.04 x32

Tags: ogg-opus

I have Ubuntu 12.04 x32
To install opus-tool like described [here](http://blog.jamesslocum.com/post/36673134166/installing-opus-101-and-libogg-13-on-ubuntu) I need to update from libogg 1.2.2 to libogg 1.3.0
I copied libogg.so.0.8.0 to i386-linux-gnu/ and made ldconfig, like in manual.
But when I'm trying to **./configure** opus-tools, getting error:

```
configure: error: newer libogg version (1.3 or later) required
```

Could you help me with that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you can upgrade so...
You can install 1.3 not as an update:

```
cd /tmp && wget -O libogg-1.3.0.tar.gz http://goo.gl/vHzMn
tar zxvf libogg-1.3.0.tar.gz && cd libogg-1.3.0
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

Comment: @fapw Glad it worked :)

Comment: Just one editing - cd libogg-1.3.0 in place of cd libvorbis-1.3.3